# Reduce time complexity of pairwise dictionary construction

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, big-o

Let say I have **dict**

```
slots = {
    "a": {"a": "Data for A"},
    "b": {"b": "Data for B"},
    "c": {"c": "Data for c"},
}
```

and a **list**

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3]
```

Now what i want that for each nested dict duplicate it the length times of list and add each object of list with some key

like this:

```
output = [
    {"a": "Data for A", "number": 1},
    {"a": "Data for A", "number": 2},
    {"a": "Data for A", "number": 3},
    {"b": "Data for B", "number": 1},
    {"b": "Data for B", "number": 2},
    {"b": "Data for B", "number": 3},
    {"c": "Data for c", "number": 1},
    {"c": "Data for c", "number": 2},
    {"c": "Data for c", "number": 3},
]
```

I have **achieved** the **desired** output by using following code:

```
output = []
for key in slots:
    for number in numbers:
        data = slots[key].copy()
        data["number"] = number
        output.append(data)
```

but the issue here is the **time complexity** which is in this case is **O(n^2)**
I want it to reduce to **O(n)** or **O(n log n)**
I did too much brainstorming and searching but could not find the appropriate solution.
One thing I found is

[https://dev.to/leandronsp/how-to-reduce-the-time-complexity-of-nested-loops-1lkd#:~:text=Putting%20all%20together,from%20the%20previously%20created%20%22index%22](https://dev.to/leandronsp/how-to-reduce-the-time-complexity-of-nested-loops-1lkd#:%7E:text=Putting%20all%20together,from%20the%20previously%20created%20%22index%22)

but don't know how to use it in my case.
May be another dict to maintain **indexes** but i couldn't figure it out how I can do it.

Any help will be appreciated, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

### What you're describing isn't possible. You can't do better than `O(n * m)`.

(where `n` is the length of the dictionary list, and `m` is the length of the `numbers` list.)

You need `O(n * m)` memory just to be able to store the result, and we need to iterate over each pair of elements from each list to generate its corresponding dictionary in the final result. Iterating over each pair alone takes `O(n * m)` time, so that gives a lower bound for how fast the algorithm can run.

You might want to look into `itertools.product()` -- it *may* be faster for your use case. But since you're asking about time complexity, the only (correct) answer that can be given is that what you're describing isn't possible.

Comment: You can take this problem as reduce the complexity of two nested loop in which inner loop variable in dependant on outer loop variable..

Comment: I don't think that's true generally, and even if it was, it wouldn't apply to this case, because the two loop variables operate independently of one another.